# FireBaseRecyclerView in FirebaseRecyclerView can not be applied to : (arguments)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase to Recyclerview. I've already implement all other steps but now i'm getting error at the last stage when i'm implementing the adapter(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter).

**My Fragment**

```
public class Journal extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference myref;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_journal,container,false);
    myref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Journal");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.journal_rv);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry, JournalHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry, JournalHolder>(
            JournalEntry.class,
            R.layout.journal_list_item,
            JournalHolder.class,
            myref) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(JournalHolder holder, int position, JournalEntry model) {
            holder.setTitle(model.getEvent_title());
            holder.setContent(model.getEvent_content());
            holder.setSchool(model.getSchool_name());
            holder.setDate(model.getDate());
            holder.setStudents(model.getNumber_of_students());
            holder.setSchoolIv(model.getImg_url());
        }

        @Override
        public JournalHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }
    };

return  v;
}
public static class JournalHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView Jtitle , Jcontent,Jschool,Jstudents,jdate;
    ImageView schoolIV;
    public JournalHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Jtitle =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.journal_title);
        Jcontent =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_content);
        Jschool =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.journal_school);
        Jstudents =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.journal_students);
        jdate =  (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.journal_dates) ;
        schoolIV = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.journal_image);





    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Jtitle.setText(title);
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        Jcontent.setText(content);
    }

    public void setSchool(String school) {
        Jschool.setText(school);
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        jdate.setText(date);
    }

    public void setStudents(String students) {
        Jstudents.setText(students);
    }

    public void setSchoolIv(String schoolIv) {
        Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(schoolIv)
                .into(schoolIV);
    }
}
}
```

This is what is shown as error

```
FireBaseRecyclerView in FirebaseRecyclerView can not be applied to :
 JournalEntry.class  (java...consti.last.database.JournalEntry>)

R.layout.journal_list_item  (int)
BlogViewHolder.class  (java...consti.last.Journal.BlogViewHolder>)
myref  (com...firebase.database.DatabaseReference)
```

Please help me. I tried all the methods but nothing works.
Or if you have any advice...thank you in advance.

**PS : I'm using Fragments**
 [image: That error is shown here]

Comment: did you write in build.gradle compile 'compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:x.x.x'?  //by x i mean latest version

Comment: in the error it says blogviewholder but you have journalholder as parameter

Comment: I'm using firebase-ui database 11.4.2, about that error i've already change to blogViewholder but it still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under Activity declaration write:-

```
  private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry, JournalHolder> adapter;
```

then inside onCreateView():

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry, JournalHolder>(
        JournalEntry.class,
        R.layout.journal_list_item,
        JournalHolder.class,
        myref) {   //be sure that these classes and parameters are correct..
```

above `return  v;`:

```
     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Use this method instead of onBindViewHolder:

```
 @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(JournalHolder holder,JournalEntry model, int position) {
```

Be sure you have all the correct methods in the model class `JournalEntry.class` and holder class `JournalHolder.class` and that its the right location and right layout.

Comment: Not working ? I've also tried this but it is not working http://5ncode.blogspot.com.ar/2017/03/example-of-firebase-recylerview.html?m=1

Comment: The new error is class 'Anonymous class derived from FirebaseREcyclerAdaper 'must be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'oncreateViewHolder (ViewGroup, int)' in 'Adapter . When i implement that method i have the same code behind.

Comment: @user8773560 did you write the declaration under, `public class Journal extends Fragment {`?

Comment: Yes , may be i' m using wrong firebare-ui database?

Comment: no its not the problem, instead of `onBindViewHolder` try `populateViewHolder` but keep the parameters the same

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solution here:[Firebase RecyclerView](http://camposha.info/source/firebase-recyclerview/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In this version FirebaseResycleView use the following:

```
  Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(); // you can add child as .child("child_name");


  FirebaseRecyclerOptions<JournalEntry> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<JournalEntry>()
            .setQuery(query, JournalEntry.class)
            .build();

  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry, JournalHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<JournalEntry, JournalHolder>(
        options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(JournalHolder holder, int position, JournalEntry model) {
        holder.setTitle(model.getEvent_title());
        holder.setContent(model.getEvent_content());
        holder.setSchool(model.getSchool_name());
        holder.setDate(model.getDate());
        holder.setStudents(model.getNumber_of_students());
        holder.setSchoolIv(model.getImg_url());
    }

    @Override
    public JournalHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.journal_list_item, parent, false);
            return new JournalHolder(view);
    }
};
```

And after don't forget:

```
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
```

Comment: Thank Дмитрий Поляков for answering my question. This is very interesting. But I don't know where I should place that code.  Can you explain it more?